# How to hardcode subtitles into a video without converting it?

Tags: video

I was searching through the internet and wasn't come up with the answers I need.

I need to hard code a subtitle to a video `.avi` for it to play on the DVD player.

But I'm looking up ways to hard code it without having a conversion.

Like, all the process I need is to stick the `.srt` file with the `.avi` file.

The conversion took me almost an hour, but I need a quick way too hard code subtitles.

Comment: Couldn't you just do it with VirtualDub?

Comment: Unless you mean soft subbing? But I'm not sure what your player supports there.

Answer (score 1):

The sole idea of hardcoding is that the subtitles are part of the actual video bitstream. This means that any subtitle text is in fact just comprised of pixels, like anything else in the video.

In order to achieve that, you obviously need to encode the video.

So, there's no way to achieve what you want.